# Need help completing code for password conversion

Tags: python, button, tkinter, passwords, output

I'm very new at Python and need some help finishing the code. This is Tkiner related.  I have an entry box, a button, and a lower frame for the output.

```
def loop_over_input(the_str=''):
    master_list = []
    for char in the_str:
        tmp_char = passwordConversion[char]
        master_list.append(tmp_char)
    print("Master Pass List: ", master_list)
    return master_list
```

This will work in command line with a couple of other lines. I'm not sure how tell it when I put text in the entry field and click the button to return the results in my lower frame. I have moved def loop_over_input to different parts of the code I think I may need to reference the test entry box and the button and the lower box.

I will post the complete code if requested to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to indent your code correctly. Everything that is in the function `loop_over_input` needs to be indented once more than the line `def loop_over_input(the_str=''):`

A few other notes. If you look up the documentation for the tkinter button, it will explain how to link a command to it. The piece of code you have supplied appears to be what you want the button command to be. Printing the list will do so in the shell, not in a frame below your entry field and button.

Here's some example code that should do what you want:

```
import tkinter as tk

# Creating tk window
window = tk.Tk()

# Master list
master_list = []
master_list_string = tk.StringVar()

# Frames
top_frame = tk.Frame(window)
top_frame.pack(expand = True, fill = 'x', pady = 10, padx = 10)
bottom_frame = tk.Frame(window)
bottom_frame.pack(expand = True, fill = 'both', padx = 10)

# Entry box
myEntry = tk.Entry(top_frame)
myEntry.pack(side = 'left',expand = True, fill = 'x', padx = 10)

# Label to display master list
myLabel = tk.Label(bottom_frame, textvariable = master_list_string)
myLabel.pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')

# Button to submit
def clicked():
    master_list.append(myEntry.get())
    myEntry.delete(0, 'end')
    printed_list = ''
    for password in master_list:
        printed_list += "\n" + password
    master_list_string.set(printed_list)
myButton = tk.Button(top_frame, text = "Submit", command = clicked)
myButton.pack(side = 'left', padx = 10)

# Mainloop
window.mainloop()
```

The two frames allow you to have the top section with your entry and button, while the bottom frame is for your output. However, you cannot just use a frame as your output, as your frame can't display text. Instead, use a `Label` widget linked to a `StringVar` which allows the text in the `Label` to update when the variable is changed.

The button command then takes the string entered into the entry, saves it to the master list and then sets the `StringVar` to the updated list, which automatically updates the `Label`.

I would highly recommend ready the documentation on Effbot, it's quite easy to understand with good examples. Link [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/)